# How to get the command-line arguments of a running windows service application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

We have a windows service application. When we install the service, we pass in command line arguments to capture some values that are used by the service.
As an example, here -r is used to identify that it is an install.

```
 MyService.exe -r /url=value1 /time=value2
```

These values are stored in the local registry.

Now we want these values to be configurable. i.e, when we stop and start the service, we should be able to do something like (-s to identify start of the service)

```
 MyService.exe -s /time=newvalue
```

Now, is it possible to read this new value from the command line?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your entry point for the EXE looks something like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

You can just use the `args` array which has all the command line arguments as an array.

If you don't/can't get it in the entry point, you can use

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

to get the command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I did already use the Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() to retrieve the values. Apparently this was working but my problem actually lay while I was trying to update the registry value. I did not pass in writeable values as 'true' to Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey before I modified the exisiting value in the registry. Maybe a little bit more patience in looking a little deeper would have pointed out where the mess was for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of arguments for windows services :

1. arguments that were passed on the process start command line. You
   can get to those easily using `Process Explorer`.
2. arguments that were passed to the ServiceBase.OnStart function. This is what is used when service is started by `SC START [arguments]`. arguments passed in the method is different from "command line process arguments". So arguments passed in `SC start` is only known by the service itself.